# How to convert small numbers to float in python?

Tags: python

I have a string and i want to convert it to float. When i convert my string to float it returns me something different. My code is;

```
a="0.0000010232"
print(float(a))

What i expect: 0.0000010232
What i get:    1.0232e-06
```

So what do i need to do?

Comment: A floating point number has a value, not a presentation. `.2`, `0.2`, `2.0E-1`, and `.0002e3` are four different ways to display the same value. If you need to retain both the value *and* the presentation of a number, you'll need to keep both a string and the number. That's not very convenient or efficient, but it's also very rarely needed. You can choose the presentation of a floating point number. Contrast `print("{:.11f}".format(0.0000010232))` with `print("{:.4e}".format(0.0000010232))`. Then read https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/string.html#format-string-syntax.

Answer (score 1):

use format

`print format(0.00001357, 'f')`

**Output:**

`0.00001357`

Comment: Prints 0.000014 on Python 2.7, and produces a syntax error on Python 3.

Comment: use brackets with print()